# How do you access rails_env from the Cap deploy command?

Tags: capistrano, capistrano3

In `deploy.rb`, I believe that `:rails_env` is typically set by `require 'capistrano/rails'` found in your `Capfile`. I am using rails, but not using the built in asset pipeline and therefore, don't use capistrano/rails and was in the predicament of having to manually set `:rails_env` in `deploy.rb` when switching between staging and production deploys. This seemed rather silly as the environment is always included when executing `cap staging deploy` or `cap production deploy`. I am posting this question, as it seems like it could be a fairly common pain point with a trivial solution, but after much googling, I came up empty-handed. I therefore dug into the `Capistrano 3.1.0` source code to figure out how to access the stage variable entered on the command line and will follow up with a brief answer that does a bit of explaining.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The simple answer is to add the following line near the top of `deploy.rb`:

> set :rails_env, fetch(:stage)

The variable `:stage` gets set in `capistrano/setup` which is required in your `Capfile`. This script creates rake tasks for each stage that is defined in `config/deploy`. Inside the definition for the rake task you will find the following: `set(:stage, stage.to_sym)` which is the stage/rails_env variable from your `cap staging deploy` or `cap production deploy` command.